# C# Pass file path from file in listbox to dataconext

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datacontext

I am populating a listbox with a file. This can be done by two methods, the open file dialog command initiated by a button press and a drag/drop action into the listbox. I want to pass on the file path (for the file in the listbox) to other areas of my code. Such as a DataContext that reads the file in the listbox. Basically I want the file path to automatically update when the listbox is populated. I am new to C# so sorry if I haven't explained myself properly or provided enough information. The code for populating my listbox (named FilePathBox) and the 'Run'  button is as follows:

```
private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    //openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Csv files(*.Csv)|*.Csv|All files(*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog())
    {
        FilePathBox.Items.Clear();

        foreach (string filename in openFileDialog.FileNames)
        {
            ListBoxItem selectedFile = new ListBoxItem();

            selectedFile.Content = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
            selectedFile.ToolTip = filename;                    
            FilePathBox.Items.Add(selectedFile);
        }
    }          
}

private void FilesDropped(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        FilePathBox.Items.Clear();

        string[] droppedFilePaths = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

        foreach (string droppedFilePath in droppedFilePaths)
        {
            ListBoxItem fileItem = new ListBoxItem();

            fileItem.Content = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(droppedFilePath);
            fileItem.ToolTip = droppedFilePath;
            FilePathBox.Items.Add(fileItem);
        }
    }  
}

private void RunButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = OldNewService.ReadFile(@"C:\Users\Documents\Lookup Table.csv");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below code.

```
<StackPanel>            
        <ListBox x:Name="fileList" Height="100" Drop="fileList_Drop" DisplayMemberPath="Name" AllowDrop="True"/>
        <Button Content="Browse" Click="Button_Click"/>
        <Rectangle/>
    </StackPanel>
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<FileInfo> lst = new ObservableCollection<FileInfo>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        fileList.ItemsSource = lst;

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        if ((bool)dlg.ShowDialog())
        {
            FileInfo fi= new FileInfo(dlg.FileName);
            lst.Add(fi);
        }
    }

    private void fileList_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] droppedFilePaths = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

        foreach (string droppedFilePath in droppedFilePaths)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(droppedFilePath);
            lst.Add(fi);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be working for me. I want to be able to put a file into my listbox,hit my run button and then my program uses the file path for the file in the listbox and completes operations on that file. Maybe I wasn't clear on that. 

Essentially I want to automatically populate the file path for the following section, contained in my code above: 

`DataContext = OldNewService.ReadFile(@"C:\Users\Documents\Lookup Table.csv");`

Comment: I can not get the answer provided to work for me. Can someone please help?